# undefined method `Factory' on user_spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have ran into a quick problem. I am getting a "undefined method `Factory'" for the user_spec page. I believe I have the incorrect syntax for " let(:user) { Factory(:user) }". However I can't come up with one that works.

```
Failure/Error: let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Factory' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fc7ac31e6a8>
```

If someone can take a look at my code and help me out that would be appreciated as I am almost done testing for the password reset.

user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  describe "#send_password_reset" do
    let(:user) { Factory(:user) }

    it "generates a unique password_reset_token each time" do
      user.send_password_reset
      last_token = user.password_reset_token
      user.send_password_reset
      user.password_reset_token.should_not eq(last_token)
    end

    it "saves the time the password reset was sent" do
      user.send_password_reset
      user.reload.password_reset_sent_at.should be_present
    end

    it "delivers email to user" do
      user.send_password_reset
      last_email.to.should include (user.email)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the Factory Girl method is the following:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

Comment: Thank you. All tests pass now!

Answer (score 7):

Replace `Factory` with `FactoryGirl`, they changed that to remove ambiguity and to let the useful `Factory` namespace available.

Comment: is your gem in test environment?

Comment: Yes. It has passed other tests so I don't believe its the gem.

Comment: I'd like to understand the -1 :)

Comment: sorry that was me. It was by mistake :)